# Equivalent Windows Script to run a SQL in all databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, linux, windows

We can run a sql in all databases using the following script in unix/linux

```
#!/bin/sh

all_dbs="$( mysql  -hlocalhost  -uroot  -pmysql -Bse 'show databases')"        
for db in $all_dbs
do
    if test $db != "information_schema" -a $db != "mysql"   -a $db != "my_db" 
    then 
        echo $db
        mysql  -hlocalhost  -uroot  -pmysql $db  < temp.sql
    fi  
done
```

the temp.sql holds the select statement

Could someone helps me with the Windows Equivalent script as i am working with windows?

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a batch file or you can try [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Using cygwin you'll have a bash and a simplified GNU userland on windows. Ideally the script will work *as is*

Comment: Is there is a way other than cygwin? Do we have an equivalent SQL snippet or script can be run in windows without using third party tools like cygwin?